# Show now playing info on lock screen XAMARIN iOS

Tags: ios, audio, xamarin, bass

I use `BASS.Net` in my project to play audio files. It works well but now I'd like to show playing information on lock screen. I tried to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying` property to setup info. However it doesn't work as expected - on emulator I do see my info but now playing window doesn't understand that it's playing and shows play button. On iPhone there is no info at all. 
Not sure what to do because in mostly all examples use `NowPlaying` property. 
I need some help here. Anyone?

Comment: Would have to see some code - but http://pulkitgoyal.in/ios-music-player-on-the-lock-screen/ this looks pretty comprehensive

Comment: @solenoid , yes, I saw that article. As you can see they use MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo that I tried to use in xamarin but no luck.